# Update Cache Storage while offline

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, browser-cache

I am currently creating an application that has offline capabilities via Service Worker API. It caches the request the first time the users loads the page and if they lose connection it uses the cache to display their data.

My need is, I need to be able to update the Cache the browser has stored for the current page without a network request occurring. Ideally it would just cache the current contents or 'state' of the page.

The reason for this is the user needs to be able to interact with the application, which will modify the UI, while offline. If the user accidentally hits refresh or closes their browser app and comes back, the contents loaded from the service worker need to reflect the most recent changes the user made to the UI.

Is this possible? Currently I am trying the below code which fails saying there is no internet connection. It seems like I can't use the cache API since by design it uses 'fetch' but is there another way to update the cache?

```
    async function updateCache(){
      console.log('updating Cache...');
      const cache = await caches.open('offline');//retrieve our cache for the page    
      await cache.add('/pagetocache/', { cache: 'reload' });        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cache.add()` implicitly makes a network request to get the response body. You can use `cache.put()` to add a `Response` that you've constructed yourself to the cache.

Assuming you have some method, `generateResponseBody()`, that returns a valid [`BodyInit`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#bodyinit) (most likely a string), you can do the following:

```
async function updateCache() {
  const cache = await caches.open('offline');
  const body = await generateResponseBody();
  await cache.put('/pagetocache/', new Response(body, {headers: {
    // Set any headers here as needed.
    'content-type': 'text/html',
  }}));  
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I hadn't understood that from the docs. That pretty much answers my question so I'll mark your answer. However, do you know what that 'generateResponseBody()' method would look like? I really just need the source at the current url to be the body.

Comment: `document.documentElement.outerHTML` will roughly give you that if you have static HTML.